# An inequality about complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

How the prove the following inequality

$|z-1|^r\ge|z^r-1|$

holds for some branch of $z^r$.

where $0\le r<1$, and $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is a complex number.

If such a branch exists will be fine.

Click [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BNorm%5BE%5E%7BI+x%7D-1%5D%5E%7B1%2F2%7D-Norm%5B%28E%5E%7BI+x%7D%29%5E%7B1%2F2%7D+-+1%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2+Pi%7D%5D)
or Click [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BNorm%5BE%5E%7BI+x%7D-1%5D%5E%7B1%2F3%7D-Norm%5B%28E%5E%7BI+x%7D%29%5E%7B1%2F3%7D+-+1%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2+Pi%7D%5D), there are examples for it.

Comment: which branch of the logarithm do you want to take ?

Comment: It seems false for complex number of modulus $1$ see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%28e^%28ix%29-1%29^%281%2F2%29-abs%28e^%28ix%2F2%29-1%29+from+x%3D0+to+2pi) with $r=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I just want a branch that can make the inequality possible, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take for instance $z=-1$ and $r=\frac34$. We get
$$
|z-1|^{3/4}=2^{3/4}=(6+2)^{1/4}=1.6817928305074290861
$$
yet
$$
|z^{3/4}-1|=\left|e^{3\pi i/4}-1\right|=\left(6+4\sqrt2\right)^{1/4}=1.8477590650225735123
$$

Comment: [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Norm%5B%28-1%29%5E%283%2F4%29+-+1%5D+-+Norm%5B%28-1+-+1%29%5E%283%2F4%29%5D) seems okay (+1)